# ggsn::scalebar not being placed in the corner

Tags: r, ggmap

I am trying to add a scalebar to a map obtained from google. I want the scalebar in the topleft corner, but it isn't being placed correctly (it is a bit out from the corner). I know it has something to do with the extent of the map, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsn)
library(ggmap)

ca <- get_map(location = c(-124.29, 40.75, -123.91, 40.97), maptype = "terrain", source = "google", force = T)

ggmap(ca) + 
    coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4326), expand = FALSE) +
    scalebar(x.min = -124.29, x.max = -123.91, y.min = 40.75, y.max = 40.97, 
             location = "topleft", 
             dist = 5,
             dist_unit = "km", 
             transform = TRUE, 
             model = "WGS84",
             st.dist = 0.04)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the cordinates called in get_map() are different from what are called as the limits in scalebar.

You can use anchor call, and use the attr() to get the latitude and longitude limits of the downloaded map. Those limits can be used in anchor call.

```
ggmap(ca) + 
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(4326), expand = FALSE) +
  scalebar(x.min = -124.29, x.max = -123.91, y.min = 40.75, y.max = 40.97, 
           anchor = c(x =  attr(ca, "bb")$ll.lon+0.005,
                      y = attr(ca, "bb")$ur.lat-0.005),
           location = "topleft", 
           dist = 5,
           dist_unit = "km", 
           transform = TRUE, 
           model = "WGS84",
           st.dist = 0.04)
```

[image]